# xsl multiple value-of select - Does it always add a whitespace between elements?

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace

I have the following.

```
    <name Type="text">
        <xsl:attribute name="Value">
            <xsl:value-of
                    select="/leadOwner/firstName, 
                            /leadOwner/lastName"/>                        
        </xsl:attribute>
    </name>
```

My unit test assert below passes; (Takes in a xml payload).

assertXpathContent("FirstName LastName", "//name/@Value", result);

My question is - Does this multiple xml select always add a whitespace between the elements?

I am happy with this result but I cannot find any material online to be 100% sure that it will always do this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an XSLT `version="2.0"` stylesheet and an XSLT 2.0 processor then (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#value-of) the default value for the `separator` is "a single space (#x20)".

If you use an XSLT 1.0 processor then the `select="/leadOwner/firstName, /leadOwner/lastName"` would result in an error.

If you use an XSLT 2.0 processor but a `version="1.0"` stylesheet and the processor supports backwards compatible behaviour, then only the value of the first selected item is output.